# Create mongoDB collection for each

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I wish to create a collection in MongoDB based on an ID. Each ID should get its own collection. I tried to add the id to collection = db.id to create a new collection if one is not already there, but it doesn't work.  This just creates a collection called id.

```
 import pymongo as pm

    list = [{'id':'1', 'fruit':'apple', 'drink':'juice'},
             {'id':'2', 'fruit':'pear', 'drink':'coffee'},
             {'id':'2', 'fruit':'banana', 'drink':'milk'}, 
             {'id':'2', 'fruit':'banana', 'drink':'fanta'},
             {'id':'3', 'fruit':'mango', 'drink':'tea'},
             {'id':'1', 'fruit':'kiwi', 'drink':'cola'}]


    for item in list:
        id = item['id']

        client = pm.MongoClient("X")
        db = client.fruit_n_drink
        collection = db.id
        x = collection.insert_one(w)
```

Answer (score 0):

`db.id` is like `db['id']`. You want to use `db[id]`.

That said, it is also going to fail, because your IDs won't work with MongoDB's naming restrictions described in https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#Restriction-on-Collection-Names

**Edit**

Reading more carefully, I think that my previous statement about the documentation is not true: looks like not starting with a character number character is just a recommendation, not a restriction.

[image: From pymongo]